# WSO2 - Identity Server 6.1.0 - Configure Google as federated authenticator

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have the latest version of identity server deployed under a server, and i am trying the following tutorial from WSO2 official documentation: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/identity-federation/google/

The dispatch tutorial web app is deployed locally and is connected to the identity server.

I applied exactly the same steps as described under the documentation.

When i open: http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/ under my browser then click the login button, instead of displaying the google sign in screen, i am getting a WSO2 error page saying: Registered callback does not match with the provided url.

Under carbon.xml logs i only have this:

```
TID: [-1234] [oauth2] [2023-10-04 11:25:10,050] [1e68ca0e-8c3b-450c-ad95-d59ec6b81bf1]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.validators.AbstractResponseTypeRequestValidator} - Provided Callback URL does not match with the registered one.
```

The configured callback under the service provider is: http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/oauth2client

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-federation/google/#set-up-a-google-app

This is the 6.1.0 document related to Configure Google as a Federated Authenticator

Answer (score 0):

This error is not specific to configuring Google as a federated IDP of the application.
There is a callback URL mismatch. The callback URL configured in the actual application properties and the callback URL configured in the registered service provider in IS are two different.
Even if you configure username and password option as the authentication step of the application you will endup with the same error.

1. Go to `<TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/pickup-dispatch/WEB-INF/classes/dispatch.properties` file.
2. Check the value defined for `callBackUrl`
3. It should be `http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/oauth2client`. This is the default value in the given sample. I think you might have change the hostname of the URL or added any additional `/` something.
4. Then go to the corresponding Service Provider registered in the IS. Check the callback URL defined under inbound configurations. It should be exactly same as `http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/oauth2client`

when you are trying the pickup-dispatch application login, open the network tab of the browser and check the `GET /oauth2/authorize`  call.
[image]
The value passed in `redirect_uri` parameter is the URL encoded value of callbackurl defined in dispatch.properties file. URL decoded value of `redirect_uri` paramter should be matched with the registered service provider's callback URL

Comment: The url under the web app properties was already configured as a sample and the same one was used correctly under the service provider, but at the end, when i followed tutorial link 6.1.0, they requested to download tomcat 9 and I used the web app linked under this tutorial and the flow worked fine.